# Read only active directory option is greyd out

Tags: domain, controller, rodc

I want to deploy a RODC sever in an existing domain.I fulfilled all pre-requisite for RODC.There are two DCs in the domain both 2008 r2.When i try to install third DC in same forest,the Read only active directory option is greyd out.

It say there are two authoritative domain servers in the domain.
Forest functional level is 2008 for both the servers and adprep is also done .still option is greyd out any one please help??

many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't been clear about what you've done.  I would suggest you run **adprep /rodcprep** (or confirm you did.  You should be able to run it again to verify it's been done.  And for good measure, carefully review the TechNet article [Steps for Deploying an RODC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754629%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) and make sure you didn't miss something.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I ran adprep/rodcprep and followed all steps for deploying RODC.

Comment: What's the Forest functional level?
And are there any other messages concerning RoDCs?

Comment: forest functional level is 2008 .The other message is forest functional should be 2003 and higher but I double checked it is 2008